# Can anyone explain what is wrong wtih the below query

Tags: mysql, sql

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE (SUBSTR(CITY,1,1) 
AND SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1)) NOT IN ("a","e","i","o","u");
```

Can someone explain what's wrong with this MySQL query?

Comment: You are testing only the second filter.

Comment: `SUBSTR(CITY,1,1)` is missing a condition. You cannot make two values share a `not in`.

Answer (score 3):

Both the first *and* last letters require assertions:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LEFT(CITY, 1)  NOT IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND
      RIGHT(CITY, 1) NOT IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

We can also handle this with regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$';
```